# Conditional fields and views

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view

I have five multigroup fields each one are displayed by a conditional field with a 1 to 5 value. If I select for example 2 there's a select list field appearing with is selected data , if i select 1 there's another one with an another select data.

How do I display with wiews only the content of the choosen value of the conditional field.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way of doing this, would be to create the logic in your theme. There are many ways of doing this, one would be to add all of the possible fields, but exclude them from display, and only show the conditional field. In one of the preprocess functions for the view, you could check the raw data for the conditional field, and replace either the field, or just the the themed value, with the value of the field you want to display.

Comment: So there's no option in the Views filter that would do it or module? I'll try with theming, i would have thought there would be another way around this, but thank you very much for responding, i'll try it.

Comment: @Rustyblue100 There isn't a module for this, that I know of. It seems very site specific, so have a hard time seeing how this would be created as a contrib module. You could create a custom filter, but it requires some complex views integration.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I'll try with what you've proposed